# Running Jenkins post build step in master agent instead of slave agent

Tags: linux, powershell, jenkins, tfs

I installed Jenkins **PowerShell plug in** and configured a **post build step** that executes a powershell script which creates a TFS task to the developer who cause the failed build.

In order to create a TFS task from powershell, some windows based TFS libraries need to be installed. Therefore I need to run this post build action in a Windows environment. But some of our projects are Linux based and we need to build these projects in Linux agents.

Is there any way to run post build step in the master Jenkins agent instead of linux based slave agent?

Or is there any other solution to create a TFS task after a failed build in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround will be create a new job which will run the step (One which you want to run in post build step). Trigger this job when there is a failure. And restrict this job to run on master only. 
Job->Configure->Restrict where this project can be run-> Put the label of master here.

You have to label your master for this to work.